# SQL server/Azure SQL: NVARCHAR(MAX) vs NVARCHAR(#) vs buffer cache

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, query-performance

We are in the process of migrating our SAAS system from Oracle to Azure SQL. We anticipate that we will have less available buffer cache in Azure SQL than we have in our Oracle server (even with sliders maxed out in Azure). Our application is quite dependent on the buffer cache for performance. Selects causing table scans being run frequently will cause a lot of data to be stored in the buffer cache, and the complete page will be read. We are not able to remove these table scans completely. So, to try to reduce the need for buffer cache in Azure SQL, we are considering to store `nvarchar(max)` values out-of-row with the command

```
EXEC sp_tableoption 'MYTABLE.NVARCHARMAX_COL', 'large value types out of row', 1;
```

The idea is that this will cause less data to scan as the column values are not stored in the page and hence less data to store in the buffer cache.

Is this a correct assumption?

`nvarchar(#)` will cause a memory grant of #/2 for queries, as far as we understand.

What is the memory grant for `nvarchar(max)`?

Will memory grants compete with buffer cache memory, or will buffer cache memory have priority over memory grants?

Is there anything to gain using `nvarchar(max)` with out-of-row storage instead of `nvarchar(#)` when it comes to buffer cache usage? Or to the contrary?

We are aware of other drawbacks with `nvarchar(max)` like slower reads and writes (50%-100%?) and that it cannot be indexed.

**Some more details:**

Our application is an Applicant Tracking System. It may be so that we will be ok with the default settings for nvarchar(max), but we want to be as sure as possible that Azure SQL will handle the full operational load before the launch. We are thinking that the increased IO with out-of-row storage is small compared to the anticipated benefit of savings in query time. We are currently running stress tests to try to figure this out. A good example is the job application table, where each row in the table consists of very little data other than the cover letter, and the table is included in a lot of queries where the cover letter column is neither a part of the where condition nor in the select column list. In Oracle, this table is currently 90% cached using 47GB of the buffer cache.
We would like to inspect the buffer cache in Azure SQL in more detail, that is to see which tables are buffered and to what extent, does Azure SQL allow this?

Answer (score 1):

While Oracle and SQL are both database engines, they have different personalities in terms of how they behave and how you tune an application to get the most on each of them.  I would not start with the kind of tuning choice you are proposing on SQL - generally having small LOBs in row is a good thing and people rarely ever need to mess with that setting.  However, there are other things that are usually more important to whether you are happy in SQL Azure having moved from another DB vendor's product.  (Indexing choices is a common one where SQL Server/SQL Azure may benefit from different kinds of indexes than you are used to in another vendor's product offerings.  SQL often likes covering indexes more than some other products when choosing plans in OLTP apps).

Memory management across components in SQL is dynamic based on the needs of each component.  You don't need to tweak or worry about it much.  You may need to consider some tweaks to your app or to the kinds of query plans you prefer to balance the resource usage (say, CPU vs. memory vs. IO) and try to best use the HW available in the cloud environment as it may not align with your on-premises server.  In some situations, we have done work to get an app to use less tempdb or to index a bit more to reduce hash joins (and thus memory requirements at runtime).  Memory grants are really a function of a lot of things - not just the size of an nvarchar's max length (LOBS are more expensive than in-row by a fair amount, as you surmise).

Depending on the kind of app you have, you may benefit from things like columnstores (which are highly compressed) which may change the kinds of resources on which your app is contending.

It usually helps to post some details of the kind of app you want to move.  Is it an OLTP system?  If so, is it sharded or not?  Is it an analytical system?  You don't have to publish lots of internal details of your app, but enough to help people give more than generic advice will help.

The short answer is that you should only change that setting when the rest of your app is tuned and you have a very good reason to do so.  I haven't seen anyone touch it for years and years in engagements I've had (and I do many of them).

If you have an relationship with the Microsoft field, then I would also encourage you to reach out to them - there are often ways to get direct help/advice on how to migrate an ISV/SaaS app to SQL/SQL Azure that may be available to you.

Best of luck on your app migration!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer! I have added some more details to my original text at the top.

Comment: @ErikHoem If you are porting a relational app from Oracle to SQL I would start first with the indexing model and make sure that you are getting good query plans.  You may or may not need all the same indexes as before.  Second, if you are storing lots of text then I would enable page compression for b-trees if you plan on storing lots of LOBs in the DB.  Additionally, you should consider whether clustered columnstores may be able to help since they gzip the LOBs in that model - potentially saving lots of space.  Finally, some in Azure use cheaper blob storage to store non-metadata.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

We have done some performance testing comparing nvarchar(max) in-row with out-of-row using column values between 3000 and 3800 characters. The query times in table scans are down by 60% in favour of out-of-row. The buffercache usage is also significantly less. Read penalty about 10% compared to in-row.

To specify Out-of-row:
EXEC sp_tableoption 'MY_TABLE', 'large value types out of row', 1;

Queries to inspect the buffercache in detail:
https://www.sqlshack.com/insight-into-the-sql-server-buffer-cache/